# How to keep focus on the text box after text changed event

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, updatepanel

I have a gridview which contains a text box as a template field.the grid view is in an updatepanel.

I use the text changed event to to calculate the percentage of the first four textboxes and put the result in the fifth text box , My problem is: i always lose the focus as soon as the text changed ,and every time i was supposed to move the mouse cursor again to the target text box.How to solve this problem?I wanna to keep the focus on my text box after text changed.

My Code:

```
 private void calc()
        {
            float sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                RadTextBox txt1 = (RadTextBox)gv_Evaluation.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("txt_evaluateWeights");
                int weight;
                bool result = Int32.TryParse(txt1.Text, out weight);
                if (result)
                {
                    sum += weight;
                }
            }

            double percentage;
            percentage = Math.Round((sum / 100) * 100, 2);
            RadTextBox txt3 = (RadTextBox)gv_Evaluation.Rows[7].Cells[3].FindControl("txt_evaluateWeights");
            txt3.Text = percentage.ToString();//string.Format("{0:0.0%}", percentage.ToString());

        }
```

---

```
       protected void txt_evaluateWeights_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            calc();
        }
```

---

My aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnl_research" runat="server" CssClass="pnl">
                <div id="detailsDiv" align="center" style="width: 800px;">
                    <table border="0" width="98%">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                                <asp:Panel ID="panel_rmv" runat="server" Visible="true" Direction="RightToLeft">
                                    <div class="grid" dir="rtl">
                                        <div class="grid" dir="rtl">
                                            <div class="rounded">
                                                <div class="top-outer">
                                                    <div class="top-inner">
                                                        <div class="top">
                                                            <h2>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="Label35" runat="server" Text="##"></asp:Label></h2>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="mid-outer">
                                                    <div class="mid-inner">
                                                        <div class="mid">
                                                            <asp:GridView Width="100%" ID="gv_Evaluation" CssClass="datatable" AllowSorting="True"
                                                                runat="server" TabIndex="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" GridLines="None"
                                                                OnRowDataBound="gv_Evaluation_RowDataBound">
                                                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                                    <table style="width: 100%;">
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                            &nbsp;
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td align="center">
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Font-Size="16pt" Text="&#1604;&#1575; &#1610;&#1608;&#1580;&#1583; &#1576;&#1610;&#1575;&#1606;&#1575;&#1578;"></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                &nbsp;
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                                <Columns>
                                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="م">
                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblSerial" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="" DataField="activityType" />
                                                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="" DataField="activityWeight" />
                                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txt_evaluateWeights" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txt_evaluateWeights_TextChanged">
                                                                            </telerik:RadTextBox>
                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="" DataField="activitySelf" />
                                                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="" DataField="activityBoss" />
                                                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="" DataField="activityDean" />
                                                                </Columns>
                                                                <RowStyle VerticalAlign="Top" CssClass="row" />
                                                            </asp:GridView>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="bottom-outer">
                                                    <div class="bottom-inner">
                                                        <div class="bottom">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot , I fix my problem:

Firstly:

because no command argument property for the textbox to store the gridview index , i store it in the tab index .

```
TabIndex='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>'
```

---

```
 protected void txt_evaluateWeights_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calc();
           int index = ((RadTextBox)sender).TabIndex;
           ((RadTextBox)gv_Evaluation.Rows[index + 1].Cells[3].FindControl("txt_evaluateWeights")).Focus();
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Is the textbox in an UpdatePanel? Is the entire page getting posted?</strike>

You could set the focus in the code-behind...

```
protected void txt_evaluateWeights_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    calc();
    ((TextBox)sender).Focus();
}
```

Comment: hmmm , aftar  i click `tab` the result appear in the last text box and the focus return to the `sender` but  i wanna the text box after i click the `tab` . because the user already has writing in this textbox.

Comment: i mean , i input data in the first text box .after moving to the next text box through `tab`. the focus return to the first one not the second one i wanna to work on.

Comment: i mean the button in the keyboard to move to the next text box

Comment: i update my question , and put the entire update panel.to clarify the structure.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jquery to do it

```
$('#txt_evaluateWeights').focus();
```

or normal javascript

```
document.getElementById("Box1").focus();
```

Comment: You should add an onblur event on the textbox, and write the above code in it

Comment: it 's asp:TextBox (server control).

Comment: yeah, I know it is a asp:textbox, you can add an onblur event on it. did you try it.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void TxtPaidAmtTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = ((TextBox)sender).TabIndex;
    TextBox txtindex = (TextBox)gridCurrentFeeHead.Rows[index + 1].FindControl("TxtPaidAmt");
    txtindex.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are trying to accomplish.
The problem I had was changing the value of a text box has affects on other text boxes.

When the user tries to type in 1.23 each time, the text change function gets called, and it puts the cursor at the beginning of the box.   So I would end up with 32.1 in the box.

To solve this I made a copy of the text in the box.  Then on textChanged, I did a character by character comparison to the saved text with the current, to get the current cursor location.

Then at the end of the TextChanged function I re-saved the new text and set the cursor back to the spot is was before the call.  using:

```
thisTextBox.Select(cursorLocation, 0);
```