# How to store hidden number in the textbox "property"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, properties, controls

I wanna to store some **hidden** data in my text box . Is there any property like  `CommandArgument` for the buttons to store my data? The text boxes are in the template field in a grid view and i get those data in text changed event of every one.

**EDIT:**

```
TabIndex='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>'

protected void txt_evaluateWeights_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calc();
           int index = ((RadTextBox)sender).TabIndex;
           ((RadTextBox)gv_Evaluation.Rows[index + 1].Cells[3].FindControl("txt_evaluateWeights")).Focus();
        }
```

I wanna to replace the `TabIndex` with a convenient property to hold my index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you use the HTML5 "data-" attribute. Then you can easily extract it using jquery.

```
<textarea name="MyTextArea" data-arbitraryName="HIDDEN TEXT" cols="40" rows="5">
    Enter your comments here...
</textarea>

<input type="text" name="MyInput" data-arbitraryName="HIDDEN VALUE" />
```

Then you'll extract it like so

```
$("textarea").data("arbitraryName") === "HIDDEN TEXT";
$("input").data("arbitraryName") === "HIDDEN VALUE";
```

So now with ASP.NET WebForm controls, you can add the `arbirtaryName` to your `RadTextBox` in your codebehind

```
var foo = "HIDDEN TEXT";
RadTextBox1.Attributes.Add("arbirtaryName", foo);
```

Here's some further reading
http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/
http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Thanks, but i don't understand it.i don't need the `textarea` or `input type ="text"` to be shown in the page . Can u explain more please through my asp.net code please.

Comment: You can add a `data` attribute` (key/value pair) on any html element. so you would have `<input type="text" data-ColumnID="555">` Then you can extrapolate **555** from the input using either jQuery or your CodeBehind and searching for `ColumnID`

Answer (score 2):

You can store such a value in the `Hidden Field` Control, since the `textbox` doesn't have any such property to store such a value.

Comment: hmmm, but i wanna a text box in my case :) .

Comment: Can you provide some details, may be I can give you any other idea how can it be done.

Comment: because i get the value in text changed event . i wanna to replace the`tabindex` property with other properety.in this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748625/how-to-keep-focus-on-the-text-box-after-text-changed-event/6840619#6840619

Comment: What is other property? What actually you want to set

Comment: other property , i mean any property to hold my hidden index.rather than the tab index because  it causes some problems.

Comment: Just think, You can store the value in TabIndex Property and you can get that value from TabIndex, and ultimatly you want to change the TabIndex and set the New value. Got my point?

Comment: @just_name let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1997/discussion-between-muhammad-akhtar-and-just-name)

Answer (score 1):

You cnanot do this directly, but using a hidden text box will enable you to store data alongside a text box. With some care, you should be able to identify the apprepriate hidden control, and extract the relevant number within the textboxchanged method.

Alternatively, there might be other ways to achieve your aim, if you give more details.

Comment: I wanna to replace the`tabindex` property with other properety to hold the index, because the tab index makes some probelms.in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748625/how-to-keep-focus-on-the-text-box-after-text-changed-event/6840619#6840619

Comment: 1. wanna is not a word. 2. Do not try repurposing existing properties. Almost always, it causes problems.

Comment: @Schroedingers Cat, not sure if it's necessary to correct grammar/spelling on this programming site. Some people spell atrociously, however just_name got his point across just fine.

Comment: @just_name, it's true, don't re-purpose an existing property, see my answer on how to have your own custom property for exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry - normally I don't bother, but "wanna" really winds me up.

Answer (score 1):

```
YourAttributeName='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>'


protected void txt_evaluateWeights_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calc();
           int index = ((RadTextBox)sender).Attribute["YourAttributeName"];
           ((RadTextBox)gv_Evaluation.Rows[index + 1].Cells[3].FindControl("txt_evaluateWeights")).Focus();
        }
```